# Using MongoDB Group on embedded documents

Tags: mongodb

My document *used to* look like this:

```
{
  _id : 47cc67093475061e3d95369d, 
  Name : "A name", 
  Description  : "Some description",
  DisciplineCode  : "105",
  DisciplineName  : "A Name",
  OtherProperty : "Something"
}
```

For which, the following group command worked, in order to get the distinct DisciplineNames and DisciplineCodes from my documents

```
disciplines = db.result.group({ 
    key: {DisciplineName:1, DisciplineCode:1}, 
    reduce: function(obj, prev) { if (!obj.hasOwnProperty("DisciplineName")) { 
        prev.DisciplineName = obj.DisciplineName; 
        prev.DisciplineCode = obj.DisciplineCode; 
    }}, 
    initial: { } 
});
```

However, my document has now changed to:

```
{
  _id : 47cc67093475061e3d95369d, 
  Name : "A name", 
  Description  : "Some description",
  Discipline: {
    Code  : "105",
    Name  : "A Name"},
  OtherProperty : "Something"
}
```

As you can see, `Discipline` is an embedded doc.

How can I modify my group command to still do the same?

Comment: Can you confirm that your reduce function is correct? If obj doesn't have "disciplineName" field, set the previous document's name field to a value that doesn't exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that you are trying return a document that lists all distinct combinations of discipline code and name.  In your first group command, I don't think the reduce function is called (please correct me if I'm wrong).

To get all distinct combinations of discipline now that code and name are embedded, you can use dot notation:

```
db.example.group({
    key: {"discipline.name": 1, "discipline.code":1},
    initial: {},
    reduce: function(obj, prev){}
})
```

input:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "doc" : { "name" : "Jenna", "number" : 1 } }
{ "_id" : 2, "doc" : { "name" : "Jenna", "number" : 2 } }
{ "_id" : 3, "doc" : { "name" : "Jenna", "number" : 2 } }
{ "_id" : 4, "doc" : { "name" : "J", "number" : 2 } }
{ "_id" : 5, "doc" : { "name" : "J", "number" : 1 } }
```

result:

```
[ 
        {
            "doc.name" : "Jenna",
            "doc.number" : 1
        },
        {
            "doc.name" : "Jenna",
            "doc.number" : 2
        },
        {
            "doc.name" : "J",
            "doc.number" : 2
        },
        {
            "doc.name" : "J",
            "doc.number" : 1
        }
    ]
```

Comment: Please let me know if this is not what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: can we give a condition also in this ??